# How do i find the mean

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def get_mean_temperature(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lst = f.read().splitlines()
        lst.pop(0)
        result = 0
        count = 0
        for element in lst:
            count += 1
            el = int(element[6:])
            result += el
        print(result)
        mn_tem = result / count
        return mmn_tem

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "temp_log.txt" 
    with open(filename, "w") as f: 
        f.write("DATES T.\n07-01 28.0\n08-01 33.5\n09-01 27.0\n")

    mean_temperature = get_mean_temperature(filename)
    print(f"{mean_temperature:.1f}")
```

This is the code that I am trying to solve. So what I have to do here is to find the mean of temperature that are given in the text file, which are in this case **"DATES T.\n07-01 28.0\n08-01 33.5\n09-01 27.0\n"**
The text is sorted by MM-DD TT.T
Please help me have this code to work

Comment: `28.0` is not an INT. If your code gives you an errormessage and a stacktrace: add them [edit] into your post - it helps us help you. Also: your last line is empty so that might get bad as well - do not do things with empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from statistics import mean

data = "DATES T.\n07-01 28.0\n08-01 33.5\n09-01 27.0\n"

temperatures = [float(item.split()[1]) for item in data.split("\n")[1:] if item]
temperatures_mean = mean(temperatures)

print(temperatures)
print(temperatures_mean)
```

Output:

```
[28.0, 33.5, 27.0]
29.5
```

Or, as your original function:

```py
from statistics import mean

def get_mean_temperature(filepath):
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        data = f.read()
    temperatures = [float(item.split()[1]) for item in data.split("\n")[1:] if item]
    return mean(temperatures)
```